# Eventos de um userControl customizado executados ainda no código no visual studio, é um bug?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2017

Estou desenvolvendo em WPF, e enquanto fazia um userControl customizado, tive uma surpresa, quando fui utilizar os Eventos "RoutedEventHandler Loaded" e "RoutedEventHandler Unloaded" do "System.Windows.FrameworkElement", notei que eles disparavam quando eu escrevia no código.. Não sei se isso é normal, mas eu acho que se trata de um bug, pois teoricamente não era para disparar o evento sem a aplicação estar em execução. Isso é mesmo um bug, ou tem uma explicação?

Se alguém quiser testar o vou colocar o código.. (Estou usando o vs2017 Enterprise, framework 4.7.2)

userControl.cs: (userControl Customizado)

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace wpf.componentes
{
    public class userControl : UserControl
    {
        private Window janelaAtual = new Window();
        private int i = 1;

        public userControl()
        {
            Loaded += userControl_Loaded;
            Unloaded += userControl_Unloaded;
            janelaAtual.Content = Window.GetWindow(this);
        }

        private void userControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            InicializarConteudo();
        }

        private void userControl_Unloaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            FinalizarConteudo();
        }

        public virtual void InicializarConteudo()
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Carregar conteúdo nº: " + i);
            i++;
        }

        public virtual void FinalizarConteudo()
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Finalizar conteúdo nº: " + i);
            i++;
            janelaAtual.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="wpf.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:wpf="clr-namespace:wpf.componentes"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <wpf:userControl />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
using System.Windows;

namespace wpf
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Após ter esse código escrito, só de compilar sem executar a aplicação, e visualizar o MainWindow.xaml.. vai aparecer a mensagem, filha da instância do Visual Studio, pois não consigo fazer nada no VS até dar OK na mensagem, depois tentem comentar o trecho onde eu incluo o userControl no MainWindow.xaml, a mensagem vai aparecer de novo..

Comment: visualizar o MainWindow.xaml, você diz abrir ele em modo design?

Comment: é no xaml, sem design..

Comment: Mas pera, como você sabe que ele está disparando esses eventos, se você não está rodando a aplicação e nem debugando o seu código?

Comment: leu o post até o fim? só de compilar a aplicação, sem executar nada, nem entrar em debug, o evento dispara no próprio visual studio.. logo depois, fiz o teste desmarcando o design em "Tools > Options > XAML Designer > Enable XAML Designer", e não disparou mais.. provavelmente quando renderiza o Design, está executando os eventos.. mas teoricamente não era para disparar, pode testar aí.. para mim isso é um bug, mas estou procurando explicações antes de reportar

Comment: leu a minha primeira pergunta? Brincadeira... cara não me parece um bug de fato... Se você tem a rederização de alguns componentes em alguma instância, alguns eventos podem ser invocados... o userControl foi carregado pela main, não? Mas nesse caso, é apenas por curiosidade ou isso está lhe atrapalhando de alguma forma?

Comment: hahah.. desculpe se fui rude, difícil me explicar por aqui, n utilizo mto esse site.. sim, me atrapalha, pq a cada vez que compilo, são executados os eventos, e para fazer testes, eu coloco essas mensagens.. mas para resolver esse problema, removi o design.. fiquei curioso, e se tratar de um bug, posso reportar para corrigirem isso ;D